# Python 2.7: Odd importing behavior

Tags: python-2.7, import, path, pywinauto

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UME1D.png)

I have:

```
C:/Python27/site-packages
```

in my Path (as shown in the screenshot.)

I also have the folder pywinauto within C:/Python27/site-packages, so I have

```
C:/Python27/site-packages/pywinauto
```

That folder contains some modules which I use. For some reason I can import pywinauto by typing:

```
import pywinauto
```

but it's contents are not imported unless I explicitly say:

```
from pywinauto import <module>
```

I think I have everything setup correctly, is there anything that is being overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules internal to a package are not automatically imported when you import the package. When you import a package, only its `__init__.py` gets executed. In many cases it contains nothing, but it's common to put there some definitions and other imports.

So, in `pywinauto/__init__.py`, include this line:

```
import application
```

Then, this should work:

```
import pywinauto
print pywinauto.application
```

The alternatives are to import like this:

```
import pywinauto.application
```

Or like this (as you already suggested):

```
from pywinauto import application
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Before I updated my computer I used to have to use application by saying pywinauto.application(). Will that be the same or will I now just use application()?

Comment: @user1367204, with `import pywinauto.application`, it is accessed as `pywinauto.application`. with `from pywinauto import application`, simply use `application`.